# Does $f(a)=1$ and $f'(x)=g\big(f(x)+x\big)f(x)$ imply that $f$ has no roots? (Proof verification)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, proof-verification

Let $f: I \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable, where $I$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$. Let $a \in I$. Let $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. If $f(a)=1$ and $f'(x) = g\big(f(x)+x\big) f(x)$, then prove that $f(x)=0$ does not have any solutions in $I$.

Is the following correct?

Let's say we have a $t$ that belongs in $I$ so that $f(t)=0$, then:

$$\lim_{x\to t}f'(x) = \lim_{x \to t} g\big(f(x)+x\big)f(x) \tag1$$

We know that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to t} g\big(f(x)+x\big) = b$ where $b \in \Bbb R$, so $(1)$ becomes $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = b \ \mathrm dy$. Then, $b=\frac1{\mathrm dx}$, which is false because $b$ cannot tend to $\infty$. Can I cancel out $\mathrm dy$?

Comment: Lerigorilla: what is the language of the original question?

Comment: Kenny Lau: It is in Greek

Comment: $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = b\ \mathrm dy$ doesn't make any sense

Comment: It does graphically

Comment: It's unwise to make an argument off of treating $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ as an actual fraction, at least when one is unfamiliar with the rigorous definitions and theory of infinitesimals. It's simply notation, and it's not a fraction in analysis; it is a limit.

Comment: Unwise, i dont argue with that, but why is it false

Comment: Not just a notation but the geometric concept behind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a rigorous proof lets recast our problem a bit. Assume $f:[-1,1]\to \Bbb R$ is differentiable, $f(0)=0$ but for $x>0$ you have $f(x)>0$. We want to show that there is a contradiction if there exists a continuous $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ so that $f'(x)=f(x)g(f(x)+x)$. If you want I can explain how solving this problem is the same as solving the above one.

Since $f(0)=0$ we can find a differentiable $h$ so that $f(x)=xh(x)$ (this is sometimes called the Morse Lemma, specifically $h(x)=\int_0^1 f'(tx)\,dt$). It follows that
$$f'(x)=h(x)+xh'(x)\overset!= f(x)g(f(x)+x)=xh(x)g(x(h(x)+1))$$
for $x>0$ divide by $xh(x)$ (because $f$ is non-zero here, so too must $h$) to get:
$$g(x h(x)+x)=\frac1x+\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}\qquad\text{whenever }x>0$$
Now taking the limit $x\to0^+$ gives $g(0)$ on the left, so it should also do so on the right. First note that $\frac{h'(x)}{h(x)}=\partial_x\ln(h(x))$ and if the term on the right is to have a limit you must have that
$$\partial_x \ln(h(x)) = -\frac1x + c(x)$$
where $C(x)$ is some continuous function. So
$$\ln(h(x)) = \ln(1/x) + C(x)$$
where $C(x)$ is a continuous anti-derivative of $c$. It follows by taking exponentials (remember $h(x)$ is positive) that
$$h(x)=\frac{e^{C(x)}}x$$
for $x>0$. This is a contradiction to $h(x)$ being *continuous* at $0$, let alone differentiable.

Comment: I understand .Can u also tell me why I am wrong or not in the above proof

Comment: A a proof needs to use concepts and constructions that are well defined. The infinitesimals $dx$ and $dy$ don't have any well-defined meaning in the context of analysis, doing manipulations on them is a purely formal undertaking and cannot prove anything. However because they do have an unrigorous geometrical meaning, working with them may be a fast way to see true results, but you cannot know whether these are true or not. Infinitesimals are well defined in the context of non-standard analysis, but this is a can of worms I do not want to open.